# identify humorous short story about spicy pizza defeating a dragon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dragons, humor

I recall reading this in a collection of short fantasy (possibly sci-fi and fantasy) in a library circa 1990.  In  the story a man goes off to fight a dragon.  I don't recall the exact details but I believe he cooks an extremely spicy dish, I'm pretty sure some kind of pepperoni pizza, and feeds this to the dragon to defeat him.

The entire story is written in a kind of psuedo Italian manner of speech (possibly offensively so).  It stuck with me in part because I was curious if the author were actually Italian, or more likely was just lampooning Italian.  (never found out).

Comment: _Not_ the answer, and too recent to be worth a "partial match" answer, but honorable mention to [_Dragons Love Tacos_](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13337050-dragons-love-tacos) (2012): _"Unfortunately, where there are tacos, there is also salsa. **And if a dragon accidentally eats spicy salsa . . . oh, boy. You're in red-hot trouble.**"_

Comment: @Jenayah To be fair, *everyone* loves tacos! :D